# How to add extra fields in products ordered report

Tags: magento-1.7, reports

We want to show extra fields in products ordered report. Extra fields are sku, cost_price(new attribute) and sold price(price)

I have found following class which handle this.

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Product_Sold_Grid
```

And also I found following controller class which handle this.

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Report_ProductController
```

I was failed to full fill this requirement. Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Open app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Report\Product\Sold\Grid.php and put the below code in `_prepareColumns()` function

You can move `Grid.php` in your local folder as well.

```
$this->addColumn('sku', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('reports')->__('Product Sku'),
    'index'     =>'sku'
));
```

Code Taken From: http://chandreshrana.blogspot.in/2016/08/add-sku-column-in-products-ordered.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a field in `sales_flat_order` table and just use following code:-

for save data:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orders->setYourField($data);
```

for display

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$orders ->getYourField();
```